# Manipulating List<List<Object>> into List <List<Object >> other format

Tags: java, list, collections, set

Input :
I want to manipulate `List<List<Object>>` in another format. Below I am providing input and expected output format

**Sample Input:**

```
List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> list4 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> list5 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> list6 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.add("Siva"); 
list1.add("20");
list1.add("Hyd");
list1.add("India");  

list2.add("Siva");    
list2.add("22"); 
list2.add("Banglore"); 
list2.add("India");

list3.add("Ramesh"); 
list3.add("22");
list3.add("Chennai"); 
list3.add("India");

list4.add("Ramesh"); 
list4.add("24");
list4.add("Kochi"); 
list4.add("US");

list5.add("Suresh"); 
list5.add("25");
list5.add("Chennai"); 
list5.add("UK");

list6.add("Suresh"); 
list6.add("24");
list6.add("Hyd"); 
list6.add("UK");

data.add(list1);
data.add(list2);
data.add(list3);
data.add(list4);
data.add(list5);
data.add(list6);
```

I need out put in below format. I need to construct another List of list obejects in below format
Need out put in distinct names, distinct age, distinct city, distinct state

**Sample output:**
[[Siva,Ramesh,Suresh],[20,22,24,25],[Hyd,Banglore,Chennai,Kochi],[India,US,UK]]

Comment: `data.add(list1);` will not compile since list1 is a list of `Object` and data is a list of lists of `String`

Comment: If you want distinct elements you should probably use Set instead of List.

Comment: @Pshemo - Can you please provide sample code

Comment: Honestly this looks like not very complex problem so I am assuming it is some kind of homework, in which case I would like to first see your best honest attempt.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the number of the sets in the resulting list.

```java
int longest = 0;
for (List<Object> items : data) {
    longest = Math.max(longest, items.size());
}
```

2. Pre-populate the resulting list with set implementation (should be `LinkedHashSet` as long as the order of insertion is needed).

```java
List<Set<Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < longest; i++) {
    result.add(new LinkedHashSet<Object>());
}
```

3. Iterate through the inner lists.  Each entry at the given index in the list is put/added to the set at the related index in the `result`.

```java
for (List<Object> items : data) {
    for (int i = 0, n = items.size(); i < n; i++) {
        // ... hometask to complete ...
    }
}
```